# jep went wrong when interpreting python in java

Tags: java, python

the java code is

```
String SCRIPT_PATH = "D:\\codes\\Python\\StockDataAnalysis\\MatGraph.py";
    try {
        Jep jep = new Jep();
        jep.runScript(SCRIPT_PATH);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and it throws exception:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

Python is no doubt installed correctly, for I can run python project on PyCharm. Jep is also set correctly, with lib path added to the PATH in windows System

Comment: Please check http://www.badkernel.com/2011/05/python-java-jep-started/  . Have you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_PRELOAD ?

Comment: I've added LD_LIBRARY_PATH:C:\Windows\System32\;.  and  LD_PRELOAD : C:\Windows\System32\python25.dll ; C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\server

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating instance of Jep like so:
`new Jep(false, path);`
where as per javadoc (https://github.com/mrj0/jep/blob/master/src/jep/Jep.java#L299):

> @param interactive
>              whether {@link #eval(String)} should support the slower
>              behavior of potentially waiting for multiple statements
>  @param includePath
>              a path of directories separated by File.pathSeparator that
>              will be appended to the sub-intepreter's sys.path

This approach worked for me in similar case. In my case `path` was pointing to a directory

> ...virtualenv\projectname\Lib\site-packages

created for my virtual env where all my python libs for my project are stored.
Please notice that you need to install jep inside of that virtual env first in order to make it work.